# Inject static resources into Spring MVC view

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Spring MVC but I am new to thymeleaf and I want to know if the following is possible, since I could not find similar questions:

Let's say I have a thymeleaf template like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/page.css}" href="../static/css/page.css"/>
</head>
...
</html>
```

For some reason I cannot send css and js files from backend, but I can send views. So when browser gets this thymeleaf page, it tries to acquire this css file and fails to get it.

So, is it possible to inject css (or js) into html file (spring-mvc view) before sending it to client? 
I want browser to get html+css (+js) in a single request so it won't send another request to get css (js).

Thanks in advance!